# Drupal content sync

Tags: php, drupal, rest, soap, xml-rpc

I have 3 drupal sites. 2 of the drupal sites are public site (.com site), the third one is an internal site behind a firewall. The site behind the firewall runs in Linux and MySQL, but pull data from the office MS-SQL and create nodes from it. The questions is:

How can I update the other 2 drupal sites content from the office drupal site?

Note: I might not need all the same fields in the public sites as in the internal one. I would like to have a setup that not only push the content to the two external sites, but if the internal site update a node, to have its content update in the external sites as well.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [Feeds module](https://drupal.org/project/feeds) on the external sites to poll the the office site for content and import new and updated content. Since you may not need all the fields on the external sites, Feeds will let you map the fields you want from the office site, to the fields you want stored on the external sites.

Depending on what data you needed to make available from the office site, you might need to customize the available feeds, using [Views](https://drupal.org/project/views).

Comment: thank you for your quick answer. I can not pull content from the office site as it is behind a firewall, that is why I was thinking in some way of pushing the content to the external sites. Do you know is I can do that with the Feeds module or any other module?

Comment: @redhatlab - Feeds can read from a file on the server's local filesystem. Just have your office site periodically upload the file to the server, then have Feeds read the file every X minutes.

Comment: @redhatlab In that case, the Publish and Subscribe modules should do what you're looking for: http://drupal.org/project/publish http://drupal.org/project/subscribe

Comment: I was dreaming of using Drupal 7, but the last two modules you suggested are in the planning stage for drupal 7. Humm... I might have to think about it.

Answer (score 0):

A tool rather than an out-of-the-box solution, but I have used [CodeServer](https://www.drupal.org/project/codeserver) to sync settings and content from one site to another. Excerpt from the project page:

```
<?php
  // Set the node id of the node we are going to copy.
  $nid = 1234;
  // Instantiate CodeServer using the configuration named 'my_remote_site'.
  $remote = new CodeServer('my_remote_site');
  // Load a node from the remote site.
  $node = $remote->node_load($nid);
  // Save the node on the local site.
  node_save($node);
?>
```